# Spring Security without a login form

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

I am writing a java application using Spring. The application will be deployed to a Java EE container in a Linux environment, being accessed by Windows users.

Is there a way I can authenticate these users into the application without using any forms?

EDIT:
The first thing that I need to do is identify who the user is.  After reading Block 87's [article](http://blog.andyserver.com/2013/07/integrated-windows-authentication-spnego-web-applications-on-jboss-eap-6-1/), I should start looking at SPNEGO and setting up each of the environments. From that point, I should be able to implement @ticktock's answer.

Comment: Is your application PKI enabled?

Comment: Right now, we are using username/pw combo, but will be moving to smartcard Windows login. I can authenticate & authorize the user using the stored certs (when the need is implemented)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you just need to replace the UsernamePasswordFormFilter with your own authentication filter.  Easiest if you extend AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.  You'll probably have to provide your own AuthenticationProvider as well.

Comment: This is part of the solution, so I'll keep this in my back pocket for now.  The first thing I need to do is get the IWA setup so I can figure out who the user is.